# Adding a website game to facebook as an facebook game

Tags: facebook, web-applications, html

I can't add my game to facebook. The game is located at: https://messenger.ee/facebookapp1/ .  Under App Center I see a message:

> Currently Ineligible for Submission
>   Please make sure your App Details Page follows all the App Center Guidelines. Also verify that the platforms your app supports are set to YES under App Center Listed Platforms in App Details

Even though all fields are filled, it still says that something is wrong, but not what...

Can someone help me?

A picture:
[Picture from Facebook App center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zEYZt.png)

Comment: So what platforms do you have set up?

Comment: "Website" with address http://www.messenger.ee/facebookapp1/index.html

Comment: You need Canvas, if you want to get into App Center.

Comment: Ok, I added the Canvas, but now I am seeing: "The requested URL was not found on this server" Address: https://apps.facebook.com/1594287727545607/?fb_appcenter=1

Comment: Also under App Info (Games Only) it shows "Unapproved", but it doesn't say the reason.

Comment: Hello again. I forgot to submit the app for review.... Now I have to wait up to 5 working days. :-)

Comment: Apparently the submit for review was not neccessary in my case, I missed the "Namespace", which can't be empty ;)